# Не могу найти ошибку. Код не компилируется

Tags: python

Все нулевые элементы заданного массива B (10)
заменить произведением минимального и максимального элементов. Вивести минимальной и максимальный элементы, начальный и преобразованием массив.

```
    import random 
import math 
b = [0]
for i in range(10):
    all == round(random.uniform(-50,50),2)
    b.append(all)
c = b[:]
mux = b[0]
for n1 in b:
    if  n1 > mux:
        mux = n1
mix = b[0]
for n2 in b:
    if n2 < mix and n2 != 0:
        mix = n2
    for math in c:
        if math == 0:
            c[math] = round(mux * mix, 2)
print(c)
print(mix, mux, %(b))
```

Comment: да, код интерпретируется....

Comment: @entithat, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41570359/9210255

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, тогда это уже будет не питоновский код, а набор инструкций для процессора :)

Comment: @entithat, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998215/9210255

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, *They contain byte code,* этим все сказано.

Comment: @entithat, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor

Comment: на самом деле это все игра слов, и я никак не оспариваю свои слова с вами.

Comment: @entithat, да, границу сложно найти. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если говорить об ошибке, то  что вот это должно означать, по вашему :

```
all == round(random.uniform(-50,50),2)
```

И вот это ошибка, на которую интерпретатор вам указывает явно:

```
print(mix, mux, %(b))
```

И вот это сильно удивило, особенно при импортированном модуле math:

```
for math in c:
```

Но, кроме того, вы что-то такое нагородили в скрипте. Прежде, чем писать программки, неплохо-бы книжечку прочитать.

```
mx=max(b)
mn=min(b)
mlt=mx*mn
print(b)
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i]==0:
        b[i]=mlt
print(mx,mn)
print(b)
```